# How can I reduce number of fetch query in a nextjs server component?

Tags: next.js, react-server-components

I have 3 tab react component

"Event", "Additional Data", "Forum"

I want to use `Server Components` on each tab, and when the user is switch between them, refetching for fresh data.

All is fine, except the `Server Component` sending a get request to the server 5 times!!!

```
// tabs.tsx
{tab === 'event' && (
  <EventTab user={event} />
)}
{tab === 'forum' && <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading forum...</p>}><ForumTab eventId={eventId} /></Suspense>}
{tab === 'additional-data' && (
  <Suspense fallback={<p>additional-data...</p>}>
    <AdditionalDataTab eventId={event.id} />
  </Suspense>
)}
```

```
// ForumTab.tsx

import { ForumTabClient } from './forum.client';

let reqCount = 0;

async function getData(eventId: string) {
    console.log('eventId: ', eventId);

    reqCount += 1;
    try {
        const data = await fetch(`localhost/3000/forum/event/${eventId}`)

        return { data };
    } catch (error) {
        return { data: undefined };
    }
}

export async function ForumTab({ userId }: { eventId: string }) {
    const { data } = await getData(eventId);

    console.log({ data });

    return (
        <>
            {`${reqCount}`}
            <ForumTabClient data={data} />
        </>
    );
}
```

In any case the server is sending the request 5 times in dev mode, and 3 times in prod.

Anyone can explain me why, and how can I reduce it to only 1 request?